# I'm trying to send email with Django

Tags: python, django, smtp

I'm trying to send email with Django but i keep getting SMTPConnectError
[ErrorMessage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bjlm.png)
[Views.py[settings.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16jNm.png)

Comment: Welcome to  Stack Overflow, see how do I ask a good question [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Although you should get better information about your problem, but I though you could see **SMTP settings of your email/gmail or etc.**